# Como converter "arraybuffer" para "string" e vice-versa?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, blob, buffer

Estou fazendo um app móvel em HTML5 e preciso estocar dados de arquivos MP3 e imagens bitmap em localStorage. O problema é que só da pra armazenar String então preciso converter um buffer em String para estocar e depois o contrário para recuperar.

Tentei [essas duas respostas (primeira e segunda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers), mas não obtive êxito.

A primeira da o erro

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceededtestaudio.html:37
>   ab2strtestaudio.html:63 (anonymous function)XMLHttpRequest.send
>   (async)testaudio.html:132 loadSongtestaudio.html:136 (anonymous
>   function)

A segunda não da erro mas o audio não toca.

[Exemplo de como estáo meu código.](http://jsfiddle.net/LL1r2hvm/1/)

Comment: Sempre usei essas funções (da 1ª resposta) sem problemas, acho que esse erro se deve ao volume de dados ser muito grande. Experimente [essa versão "loopificada"](http://jsfiddle.net/LL1r2hvm/2/) e veja se resolve seu problema.